# EF Core: Any() doesn't filter all items

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I've got this query:

```
from supply in context.Supplies
                where
                    supply.AccountId == accountId 
                    && supply.Product.Requests.Any(r => r.WantToTrade && r.PotentialTradeSupplies.Any(p=>p.CanBeTraded))
                select supply).Include(s => s.Product)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Requests)
            .ThenInclude(r=>r.PotentialTradeSupplies)
            .ThenInclude(pts=>pts.Sizes)
            .Include(s=>s.Product)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Requests)
            .ThenInclude(r=>r.Account)
            .Include(s=>s.Product)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Gender)
            .Include(s=>s.Product)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Category)
            .Include(s => s.Product)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Division)
            .Include(s=>s.Product)
            .ThenInclude(p=>p.Availabilities)
            .ThenInclude(pa=>pa.Sizes)
```

The query returns all requests of a product, also if request.WantToTrade is false. I only want the requests where WantToTrade is true. How do I filter these out?

Comment: Maybe you should use `All` instead of `Any` when filtering requests?

Comment: did you try to .Include() your nested child entries? I'm not sure on how to do this in linq-to-sql, try the Fluent way, might work out. It seems like the nested entries are not loaded.

Comment: This query does not return product and requests, but supplies having at least one request matching the criteria. Is the query using eager loading (`Include` / `ThenInclude`) not shown in the question? Btw, LINQ to SQL and EF Core are totally different things.

Comment: I updated the code sample. It includes products, requests and potential trade supplies.

Comment: As far as I know just from reading through now, you have to .Include() your childs right with getting the supplies from the context. i.e. `from supply in context.Supplies.Inlcude(..)..` and then you can filter your query as suggested above in the comments. See the answer below from Tim Schmelter for another way of getting the data.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to remove first `Any()` filter, so your query becomes

```
from supply in list
    where supply.AccountId == accountId 
        && supply.WantToTrade 
        && supply.PotentialTradeSupplies.Any(p=>p.CanBeTraded)
select supply
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ue95P4)